# Blazor and FluentValidation

Tags: blazor, fluentvalidation

I've been tinkering with Blazor and FluentValidation as a learning process, but can't seem to get even a "Hello World!" to work.

I started a new project and added Fluent via NuGet, with a very basic data class, validator and index razor page.

No validation messages appear. I just get the dreaded "An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details." at the botton of the page. Please help me get this working.

```
using FluentValidation;
namespace TestFluent.Data
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmployeeValidator:AbstractValidator<Employee>
    {
        public EmployeeValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(n => n.Name).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please enter a name");
            RuleFor(n => n.Name).MaximumLength(30).WithMessage("Name must be 30 characters or less");
        }
    }
}
```

and the Index.razor:

```
@page "/"
@using TestFluent.Data;

<h3>Header</h3>
<EditForm Model="@emp" OnValidSubmit="@HandleSubmit">
    <FluentValidationValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-form-label">Name:</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <InputText @bind-Value="@emp.Name"></InputText>
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => emp.Name)" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
    <p><label>@msg</label></p>
</EditForm>

@code {
    string msg = "";
    Employee emp = new Employee();

    void HandleSubmit()
    {
        msg = "Success!";
    }
}
```

Edit: I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQxsQu9yg20

Dev tools error:

```
[2020-08-16T01:20:44.379Z] Error: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult> FluentValidation.IValidator.ValidateAsync(System.Object, System.Threading.CancellationToken)'.
    
           at Blazored.FluentValidation.EditContextFluentValidationExtensions.ValidateModel(EditContext editContext, ValidationMessageStore messages, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IValidator validator)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)

   at Blazored.FluentValidation.EditContextFluentValidationExtensions.ValidateModel(EditContext editContext, ValidationMessageStore messages, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IValidator validator)

   at Blazored.FluentValidation.EditContextFluentValidationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<AddFluentValidation>b__0(Object sender, ValidationRequestedEventArgs eventArgs)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditContext.Validate()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm.HandleSubmitAsync()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
```

Comment: Please share the error message it displayed in the browser dev tools.

Comment: Well, now I feel dumb. The .NetStandard version for the project was 2.0, which is not supported by the Fluent library. It appears to work with v2.1. Thanks for the response Umair.

Comment: https://github.com/mrpmorris/blazor-validation lets you use FluentValidation and the built in validation at the same time. It has other nice features such as validating the whole object tree, only validating a subset of properties (for wizard interfaces) etc.

Comment: @PeterMorris I want to use your library for fluent validation in my wizard screens, do you have a sample project for that how to use it?

Comment: bool valid = EditContext.ValidateProperties(
 EditContext.Field(nameof(SupplierCreateCommand.ApiHook1Url)),
 EditContext.Field(nameof(SupplierCreateCommand.ApiHook2Url)),
 EditContext.Field(nameof(SupplierCreateCommand.ApiHook3Url)),
 EditContext.Field(nameof(SupplierCreateCommand.ApiHook4Url)));

Comment: It's an extension method that my library adds.

Comment: Thanks, will try this

Answer (score 0):

FluentValidation does not provide integration with Blazor out of the box, but there are several third party libraries you can use to do this:

- [Blazored.FluentValidation](https://github.com/Blazored/FluentValidation)
- [Blazor-Validation](https://github.com/mrpmorris/blazor-validation)
- [Accelist.FluentValidation.Blazor](https://github.com/ryanelian/FluentValidation.Blazor)

and mine:

- [vNext.BlazorComponents.FluentValidation](https://github.com/Liero/vNext.BlazorComponents.FluentValidation) (supports most features, like async validtion, severity levels and context based validators, unlike the above mentioned)

Based on the error:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult> FluentValidation.IValidator.ValidateAsync(System.Object, System.Threading.CancellationToken)'

I guess you are referencing an older version of
FluentValidation nuget that is not compatible with newer `Blazored.FluentValidation` nuget.

These errors occurs, when there is a breaking change of those dependencies. In this case `IValidator.ValidateAsync(System.Object)'` has been changed to .IValidator.ValidateAsync(System.Object, System.Threading.CancellationToken = default)'.

According to author, such changes to FluentValidation should be avoided in the future, see https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/1915